# Headless SSH without Wi-Fi setup

Tags: networking, ssh

||| Hello there, noob question:

I've acquired my first rpi (a Zero W) three days ago and made a headless setup. Currently, it works as a logging device. I really liked the prospect of logging into the rpi through SSH without connecting a spare monitor and keyboard (after interface reduction). Currently, the rpi connects to my home WLAN on boot (using wpa_supplicant and a config file on the wlan0 interface). If I connect my computers to the same network, I'm able to SSH into the rpi from any of them, as I've learned how to setup a static local IP the rpi.

I wonder however how to extend this setup to handle a situation where I, my rpi, and e.g. my laptop travel to a previously unspecified place, where either a Wi-Fi exists and I can fetch the password only after I arrive (no rpi preparation with respect to this specific access point), or the Wi-Fi does not exist at all (e.g. a park/forest).

I've seen tutorials where an ethernet cable can be used to setup a LAN connection between the laptop and the rpi, but this solution is unfeasible (no female ethernet port on the rpi). Both my laptop and the rpi have a wifi and a bluetooth chip/card/hardware thingy. I've also thought about setting up a hotspot on the laptop and letting the rpi connect to it on boot, but I've never created a hotspot before and don't know how IP's would be assigned to both devices. Unsure whether this is more of a rpi question or a linux/networking question, but I've assumed that rpi people handle headless accesses most frequently.

Is this even possible? If yes, can you please suggest a solution? Anything at all will be deeply appretiated.

Comment: Power off. Pull the sdcard, stick it in your laptop and CANCEL any offers to reformat the device. Open a cmd.exe or powershell window and run `echo "ssh" D:\ssh.txt` (I'm assuming it appears as D:). Put it back in your RPi and reboot. SSH will be automatically activated on that boot.

Comment: @Dougie Thank you for the reply. As I said, I know how to setup SSH on the rpi and connect to it when both devices are connected to the same Wi-Fi, that is, the laptop can send packets over the Wi-Fi to a local IP address (which I've conveniently made static). What you propose is something I've already done. How would you connect to the rpi device over SSH without the Wi-Fi connection?

Comment: You can do the same for WiFi with a wpa_supplicant.conf file on D:\. If that doesn't work then I don't know what you're asking for and you'll need to rewrite your question to be clearer.

Comment: @Dougie The OP is asking how to SSH into the Pi when they are not using their own AP and can not assign a static IP address to the Pi, or when there is no AP already present and they have only their laptop and the Pi.

Comment: Can you connect to the Pi via USB Ethernet or does it have to be via WiFi?

Comment: @Andrew I can connect the rpi (microUSB) to my laptop (USB) using a microUSB - USB cable, yes. The medium over which the devices communicate (or other implementation details) is not important to me, only the fact that i can `ssh` into the rpi from the laptop.

Comment: Console cable? All you do is connect the 3/4 wires to the Pi and plug it in to your computer and you just connect to the serial port that appears. But you first need to enable serial and the console appearing on the serial connection with `raspi-config`.

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/ethernet-gadget it's a bit old but still valid.  Advantage is you use the same cable to connect the USB to power the Zero.  Note you use the USB port not the power port for this cable.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew for the reply. This looks exactly like what I'm looking for. The problem is that I have no idea which linux files are updated by putting config.txt and cmdline.txt files in the boot partition on the first boot. I'd like to avoid re-formatting the SD card.

Comment: cmdline and config files live on the boot partition so are available from initial creation of the SD card and after use as a day to day pi. Just take care with the position of text in cmdline else it can be deleted as part of initial boot.  Apt update will keep the driver files up to date and does not change their settings in the two files.

Comment: @Andrew Yeah, scratch that, I just found out about this fact. Neat! Solved. You can post an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Its also possible to configure the RPI0 as a USB gadget and do the networking via the USB cable.   Which is very handy as you get power and networking via the one cable.   Of course it needs to be plugged into a computer which recognises it and has enough amps to power the PI but thats not a problem with Windoze,Mac or Linux.

https://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-zero-ethernet-gadget/

Comment: @SimonBanks Yeah, pretty much what Andrew suggested. It is exactly what I've been looking for :) Thanks. Also, I have a T430, which has a powered USB socket, so I believe power will not be an issue.

Comment: Its like a poor mans PoE very useful....